# Read form ZipDecryptInputStream and write it to OutputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

public void decrypt(String inputFile, String password) {

```
    ZipDecryptInputStream zipDecrypt = null;
    try {
        zipDecrypt = new ZipDecryptInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                inputFile), password);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File file = new File("outouttfile.tsv");
    OutputStream fop = null;
    try {
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;      
        while ((bytesRead = zipDecrypt.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fop.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.println("Written");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My while loop becomes an infinite loop and does not stop reading the file even its read once. Any idea why?

Comment: Your while loop looks fine to me.  Are you sure it's an "infinite" loop? How many bytes are you reading each time? How big is the file?

Comment: I am reading 1024 bytes each time. The file is very small as I was in the test phase. I  also don't know why its hitting the infinite loop.

Comment: Is it the *same* 1024 bytes each time? Have you verified you're pointing to the correct file (and using the correct password?) Have you opened the file in an external editor to verify what bytes you expect to be reading? (Gotta ask all the obvious debugging-type questions first to rule them out)